# MySQL InnoDB FULLTEXT search over JSON generated STORED column is slower than LIKE

Tags: mysql, json, full-text-search, innodb, generated

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `stores` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `html` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`value`,'$.html')))
       STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `html` (`html`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Query:

```
select id from `stores`  where  MATCH(stores.html) AGAINST ('forum*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  limit 20
```

Takes 0.14 seconds

Explain:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | stores | NULL | fulltext | html | html | 0 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking, limit = 20 |

When query:

```
select id from `stores`  where   stores.html like '%forum%' limit 20
```

Takes only 0.003 seconds

Explain:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | stores | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 134101 | 100.00 | Using where |

I remember, when I first implemented this virtual generated fields over json it appeared to be faster than like, but now after implementing it over all the fields I noticed the site got slower. So I started analyzing the simple queries and found out that fulltext is actually significantly slower!

When I add SQL_NO_CACHE after select it makes no difference.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Remove the `LOWER`; it may go even faster.

Comment: Do you get the same results?

Comment: As of of LOWER removal, ok but the question is why fulltext search is slow? Same results? With LIKE I get slightly bigger number of results because it matches the string even if its a part of another word.

Comment: How long does this take?  `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(html)) FROM stores  where html like '%forum%';` ?

Comment: MAX(LENGTH(html))
75581

1 row (0.083 s)

Answer (score 0):

This query is abnormally fast:

```
select id from `stores`
    where stores.html like '%forum%' limit 20
```

Because it only looked at enough rows to find 20 that had that string.  I think you will find that this takes significantly longer since it will check every row:

```
select id from `stores`
    where stores.html like '%non-existent-text%' limit 20
```

Another possible reason is that `MATCH` found hundreds, maybe thousands, or rows before it got to doing the `LIMIT`.  So time this:

```
select id from `stores`  
    where  MATCH(stores.html) AGAINST ('qwertyui' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  limit 20
```

The bottom line is that you may need to live with such inconsistencies.  I believe (without solid proof your *your* dataset) than `MATCH` will *usually* be faster than `LIKE`.  Note the word "usually".